# angular HttpClient get method not calling the server

Tags: angular, http

My server API is up and running, but the Angular call HttpClient.get does not seem to be calling the server.

Here is the method I'm calling:

```
private url = 'http://localhost:7002/myproj/api/domain';

callServer (): Observable<string> {
    console.log("in callServer()");
    return this.http.get<string>(this.url);
}
```

And this is based on the tutorial [sample code](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-heroes-with-httpclient):

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
}
```

1) I know my API server is up and running.

2) I know the URL is correct.

3) The server isn't even logging or responding to the request (so I know the request isn't reaching the server.

4) My method `callServer()` is being called because the log message is being printed to the console.

Comment: which url is your angular app running on?

Comment: @VithuBati The angular app is running on URL `http://localhost:4200/#/`

Comment: then you can not pass another server. instead you have to use proxy for this

Comment: @VithuBati Oh really? How do I do that?

Comment: do you get any error in the console when you call?

Comment: @VithuBati No error in any console or anywhere else.

Comment: i just checked you are not subscribing to your Observable. you have to subscribe inside your component

Comment: let me know if you still dont get it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must subscribe for the http response `callServer().subscribe(x=> console.log(x))`.

Comment: How come the angular documentation example doesn't mention this? It says just calling `get()` should be sufficient.

Comment: You're following the tutorial. In tutorial [6. Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#observable-heroservice) you can find the subscribe call.

Comment: Angular httpClient by design returns a cold observable, which means that until you subscribe for it, no data will pass trough the stream and each new subscription will return brand new data from the endpoint, so that is the reason that there are no calls to the desired endpoint

Comment: What if you just wanted to assign another observable that you use in your UI with the Async pipe? EDIT... It does work... I was just subscribing to the wrong object in my template ‍♂️